# Disable Update Sites Reverts Back to Enabled

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, update, extension-update

Joomla 3.9.21

I have a number of extensions that are notifying me of updates in the Joomla dashboard, I want to temporarily disable these notifications. (*I know this isn't best practice and it's temporary*)

In `Extensions > Manage > Update Sites` I have found the extensions / components and changed their status to `disabled`. When I clear the site cache and check `Extensions > Find Updates` they are no longer in the list of available updates, great.

However they will eventually re-appear in the available updates list and their status in `Extensions > Manage > Update Sites` will revert to `enabled`.

Initially I though this was occurring with just one extension, but it appears to be all my `disabled` sites.

Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause.

I'm using a third party tool to manage, upgrade and monitor my Joomla sites. One of the features is to scan the site for available updates, during this process the update sites are all **enabled**. The developer confirmed this was the expected behaviour of the product.

I'm able to disable this feature and my updates sites now remain disabled.

Comment: That service - was it mysites.guru ? I have the same problem but I cannot find what is enabling extension servers.